# How to show BodyScreen below TopAppBar?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

So I tried to include a TopAppBar with my code, but then I got al my component to push up and gets inside `TopAppBar`
like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3aNI.jpg)

```
 TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(text = "Jetpack Compose")
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack)
                }
            }
    )
    Card(
            shape = CircleShape,
            border = BorderStroke(2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
            modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(48.dp),
            elevation = 16.dp
    ) {
        Image(
                imageResource(id = R.drawable.header),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(48.dp)
        )
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Catalin Ghita", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        Text(
                text = "Active now",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
        )
    }
```

How to just add topappbar with also using middle body screen/ background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be your Root Components is Stack/Box or you don't have any Parent components. Try to add `Column` as your root components and you can add like this,

```
Column {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = "Jetpack Compose")
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack)
            }
        }
    )
    Card(
        shape = CircleShape,
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
        modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(48.dp),
        elevation = 16.dp
    ) {
        Image(
            imageResource(id = R.drawable.header),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(48.dp)
        )
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Text("Catalin Ghita", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        Text(
            text = "Active now",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
        )
    }
}
```

Or you can use `Scaffold` to show the top bar and the body content like below.

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(text = "Jetpack Compose")
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack)
                }
            }
        )
    }) {
    Column {
        Card(
            shape = CircleShape,
            border = BorderStroke(2.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
            modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(48.dp),
            elevation = 16.dp
        ) {
            Image(
                imageResource(id = R.drawable.header),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(48.dp)
            )
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Text("Catalin Ghita", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            Text(
                text = "Active now",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolute best answer

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Scaffold` composable :

```
    Scaffold(
    topBar = TopAppBar()
){ innerPadding -> // content body goes here }
```